# How to get modified color of input's placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
input::placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Hello world">
```

I am looking over an accessibility problem, and I need to identify the applied CSS style specifically color on input's placeholder.

**What I have tried**

```js
const inputEl = document.querySelector('input'),
 styles = window.getComputedStyle(inputEl, ':placeholder');
console.log(styles.getPropertyValue('color'));
```

```css
input::placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Hello world">
```

But I am getting `rgb(0, 0, 0)`

Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code work fine for me , is see the red placeholder. which browser do you use ?

Comment: chrome, which browser you are using ?

Comment: @MathéoZeller we all see the red color but check the console log

Comment: Nop just tried on Mozilla, i get `rgb(60,60,60)` which is little light to black. Applied as per the browser style sheet

Comment: @SatyamPathak does my answer work for you? I have it working on Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Hi @Ma'mounothman - I can't update the style, I just need to get the value. It's kind of automation. So that for that case your answer is not helpful for me